# Android Gauge not Displaying Needle

Tags: android, gauge

I am using a custom gauge: [ChariotGauge](https://github.com/mikemey01/ChariotGauge)

The problem is I am not able to display the needle and only my gauge gets shown.

I have used the `gaugeBuilder.java` from the library and in my `mainactivity onCreate() instance I have added the below code:

```
minValue = 0; maxValue = 100; gauge1.setTotalNotches(80);
gauge1.setIncrementPerLargeNotch(10); 
gauge1.setIncrementPerSmallNotch(2); 
gauge1.setScaleMinValue(minValue); 
gauge1.setScaleMaxValue(maxValue); 
gauge1.setScaleCenterValue(50, true); 
gauge1.setUnitTitle("Pressure"); 
gauge1.setAbsoluteNumbers(true); 
gauge1.setValue(minValue);`
```

The [Screenshot for problem](http://postimg.org/image/t21dk133j/)

Can anyone help me out in displaying the needle. I just need to set the needle, not continuous.

Comment: it is always good to share the code so that other users can check and point out the issue and fix.

Comment: I have used the gaugeBuilder.java from the library and in my mainactivity oncreate instance i have added the below code:             minValue = 0;
        maxValue = 100;
        gauge1.setTotalNotches(80);
        gauge1.setIncrementPerLargeNotch(10);
        gauge1.setIncrementPerSmallNotch(2);
        gauge1.setScaleMinValue(minValue);
        gauge1.setScaleMaxValue(maxValue);
        gauge1.setScaleCenterValue(50, true);
        gauge1.setUnitTitle("Pressure");
        gauge1.setAbsoluteNumbers(true);
            gauge1.setValue(minValue);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all...I got the solution from  [Canvas not displaying all drawn parts in Custom View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460958/canvas-not-displaying-all-drawn-parts-in-custom-view)

I had to sent the following to `gauge` :

```
gauge1.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help

Add this in gradle

```
compile 'com.cardiomood.android:android-widgets:0.1.1'
```

layout xml-file

```
<com.cardiomood.android.controls.gauge.SpeedometerGauge
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/speedometer" />
```

ConfigureSpeedoMeters

```
private SpeedometerGauge speedometer;

  // Customize SpeedometerGauge
  speedometer = (SpeedometerGauge) v.findViewById(R.id.speedometer);

  // Add label converter
  speedometer.setLabelConverter(new SpeedometerView.LabelConverter() {
      @Override
      public String getLabelFor(double progress, double maxProgress) {
          return String.valueOf((int) Math.round(progress));
      }
  });

  // configure value range and ticks
  speedometer.setMaxSpeed(300);
  speedometer.setMajorTickStep(30);
  speedometer.setMinorTicks(2);

  // Configure value range colors
  speedometer.addColoredRange(30, 140, Color.GREEN);
  speedometer.addColoredRange(140, 180, Color.YELLOW);
  speedometer.addColoredRange(180, 400, Color.RED);
```

For more see [this](https://github.com/ntoskrnl/AndroidWidgets)

Comment: I have already used this gauge. It is taking too much space which doesnt display properly on resize and moreover it is not a circle gauge. Thanks for the reply anyways.